# Compute u•v, where $u = \sqrt{3}i -315j +22k$ and $v =\frac{u}{||u||}$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I need to solve u•v, where $u = \sqrt{3}i -315j +22k$ and $v =\frac{u}{||u||}$. Can I just plug $u$ into the equation for $v$ and solve for the length of $u$ like

$v = \frac{\sqrt{3}i - 315j + 22k}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}^3 + 315^2 + 22^2}}$
?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show us what you have done in order to get more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way:

${\bf u} {\bf \cdot} {\bf v} = {\bf u} {\bf \cdot} \dfrac{{\bf u}}{\| {\bf u}\|} = \dfrac{{\bf u} {\bf \cdot} {\bf u}}{\|{\bf u}\|} = \dfrac{\|{\bf u}\|^2}{\|{\bf u}\|}=\|{\bf u}\| = \sqrt{3+315^2+22^2}$